# Typescript error: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'A'

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

The below is an example of the types which I have

```
type Place = {
   address: string
}

type Location = {
   latLng: string
}

type User = {
  name: string
} & (Place | Location)
```

So when I try to use it while parsing the data

```
const { name, address, latLng } = user;
```

It shows a TS error **Property 'address' does not exist on type 'User'**

Technically I know that either address or latLng will be present but not both, which is how I need and my logic will validate it when parsing the data. But how to let TS know that about it and remove this error?

Comment: You can't have both `address` and `latLng` because you indicated that it should one OR another (using `|`)

Comment: @Anatoly Actually, even when I have only address while destructuring, It still shows this error. Any other way to write type for this scenario?

Comment: Seems like it take into account as known only `name` prop as the only one certain prop. You can something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=9&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwMbQLxQN4FgBQV8IAmhAThAM7kBcU5wJAlgHYDmuAvrrqJFADIB7JAmAMBTKOmx58iYH1Y06jVhy44e0AKrkIJSZlz4mCALYQl9ZmxzsoAMigAKeMmgAffkJFimASnUkcTooAFddEhodPQNpAmIyShoAcmSAGiMoOQUWFPTMk3M8tRxA4OBMLJEcqDt0cJiEci9hUXEAblwgphCMKCJSCma6sIj+5tcUTpwgA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place to use `never`. This lets you set up two "configurations" of the User, which will have either a Place or a Loc. The Place type enforces an undefined latLng, while the Loc type enforces an undefined address. A User is one of `({name: string} & Place) | ({name: string} & Loc)`, so while all three fields exist in both types in the union, address or latLng will be undefined based on the presence of the other.

```js
type Place = {
  address: string;
  latLng?: never;
};

type Loc = {
  latLng: string;
  address?: never;
};

type User = {
  name: string;
} & (Place | Loc);

function test1() {
  // Valid, latLng is undefined
  const user: User = { name: "User", address: "1234 Somewhere St" };
  const { address, latLng, name } = user;
}

function test2() {
  // Valid, address is undefined
  const user: User = { name: "User", latLng: "123,456" };
  const { address, latLng, name } = user;
}

function test3() {
  // Invalid, both address and latLng are present
  const user: User = {
    name: "User",
    latLng: "123,456",
    address: "1234 Somewhere St",
  };
  const { address, latLng, name } = user;
}
```

([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwMbQLxQN4FgBQUoIAmhAThAM7kBcU5wJAlgHYDmA3LvosADKsD8NJhABuEEhxwBfSblCQoPAPZIo6bHijc+LGnUatJ+IqQrlBUYWIm4ZuOeGgBVcuLWZOlhAFsIe+szstlAAZFAAFPDI0AA+iioAlLI4AGYArkxIwAxKTFDAFMAAjOEJHpoA9BVQAGoIcAyEADRaCLysUAzkUBmEECnMEISeSLl0Pa4kNC5u6l6+NABEMySLLSZklEtFAEwAzAAsUADKSr4A7gAW4tDHwItQdpqjTOMYBMSb5C3arC1MPmgUncaUmkik9lSGSyOTyBToO1K5XwVVq9Ua60+Zk63V6-UGw2eY2AE3E00m7neAIWUGWkzWrXaulpuz2TQOAFYAGwPJ74F5vD6mSg-No6f6Ax4gsG2SHpTLZXL5Qp7JEaFHVACSTBE6OaUAARkpgJchV8CExCIydAQyFAwJsIExgCNiaSplAVpTPPhqX5aSs1j7raxtvt2dyg5pjFitiz9kdThdrna7lH8HyoAKSe8NmZRUyJb4pehQeJwbggA))

This gives you a type which can have either a defined `address` or `latLng` but not both. You can destructure both values out of the `user`, but one or the other will be undefined.

Comment: Yes, this is also a Great way to use it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Actually I think this is a better solution in terms of code optimization. It does save few lines of condition and code.